# How to display a product from certain category in joomla virtu mart extension

Tags: joomla

I am developing a joomla virtu mart store and need to display products form certain category  in my sidebar its my second day of searching for such a mudule or some kind of hint but it did not worked for me anybody knows how can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the package for VM in the 'Modules' folder.